# Screen refresh problems following 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, screen

I just upgraded from 11.10 (running with no problems) to 12.04 and find that the screed is not refreshing. Open windows do not disappear and when i drag an open window it just replicates self. There is however no problem within a window e.g. Firefox works fine. I have a dual screen setup with an nvidia graphics card

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - I resolved it by changing my desktop background from a solid color to a gradient (any image wallpaper worked too.)